# Splunk: Splunk-python SDK: How to include pandas, numpy to create custom command

Tags: splunk, splunk-sdk

I am making a custom command for splunk, say getInfluentialCommand. So I make a .py file in bin directory. in this .py file, I need to include pandas, numpy. How to do it? Does splunk python environment allow me to include other python module? Do I just need to install as `pip install pandas` or `pip install numpy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, in directory, `etc/app/command`，use command `pip` to install `splunk python` library, also `pandas` and `numpy`.

```
pip install -t . splunk-sdk
```

Just same as splunk-sdk, one could install other libs.

Answer (score 1):

You would be best off including a `lib` directory in your app and include any dependencies from there. This is the model we recommend for including the Splunk SDK for Python in your app. Our docs on this topic are [here](http://dev.splunk.com/view/custom-spl/SP-CAAAFFS).